# Hibernate mapping - many to one relationship

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, many-to-one

previously , this is how i map my "Activity" table. This table is storing CONTACT_ID and ACCOUNT_ID which link to Account and Contact table.
[image]

in this way

```
<many-to-one
    name="accountObj"
    class="my.com.miramax.crm.account.db.Account"
    not-null="false"
    not-found="ignore"
    insert="false"
    update="false"
    column="ACCOUNT_ID"
/>
```

Now i have a table like below 
[image]

this table doesn't store the ACCOUNT_ID and CONTACT_ID, but it separated into "Table_REF" and "REF_ID". For example , TABLE_REF = "Account" and REF_ID = 239 is same as the Account_ID = 239 in the Account table.

Can anyone tell me how do i map this table, so that i can differentiate them and use it in the DAO for searching ?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following mapping ---
This will populate it based on whether ID exists in corresponding tables. You can use the following query to load the data properly.

```
"from Activity activity left outer join activity.account ac with tableref='Account' left outer join activity.contact con with tableref='Contact'"

------------

<many-to-one name="account" 
column="REF_ID"
insert="false"
update="false" 
lazy="no-proxy"
not-found="ignore"
>
</many-to-one>

<many-to-one name="contact" 
column="REF_ID"
insert="false"
update="false"
lazy="no-proxy"
not-found="ignore"
>
</many-to-one>
```

Comment: i'm new to hibernate , i cant see anywhere to apply the query in my hbm.xml, can you please tell me more details ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it sounds like a typical case for `<any>`:

```
<any name="referenceObj" id-type="long" meta-type="string">
    <meta-value value="Account" class="my.com.miramax.crm.account.db.Account"/>
    <meta-value value="Contact" class="..."/>
    <column name="TABLE_REF"/>
    <column name="REF_ID"/>
</any>
```

See the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-types-anymapping).

Comment: thanks a lot, may i know how do i apply the referenceObj create by <any> in DAO ? i want to do a searching that will filter the Account table. Usually i can do like this in DAO - "criteria.createAlias(CostCentre.PROP_CONTACT_OBJ, CostCentre.PROP_CONTACT_OBJ, Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);"